# typeORM migration:generate not recognise import baseurl

Tags: database-migration, typeorm

I am using typeORM with nestjs and typescript. I have nestjs so all import statements can start with 'src/...'  typeorm will only accept imports to other entities using ../

Not finding the referenced entity

```
import { User } from 'src/users/entities/user.entity';
```

Structure to finding the referenced entity:

```
import { User } from '../users/entities/user.entity';
```

I am using the script from package.json

```
"migration:generate": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -n"
```

ormconfig.json

```
[
 {
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "xxxx",
  "password": "xxx",
  "database": "xxxx",
  "schema": "xxx",
  "migrations": ["dist/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
  "migrationsTableName": "migrations_typeorm"
 }
]
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "module": "commonjs",
   "declaration": true,
   "removeComments": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
   "target": "es2017",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "outDir": "./dist",
   "baseUrl": "./",
   "incremental": true
  }
 }
```

nest-cli.json

```
{
 "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
 "sourceRoot": "src"
}
```

I have tried the suggestion [typeorm migration api does not generate automatic code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005652/typeorm-migration-api-does-not-generate-automatic-code) but it does not solve my issue.
How do I get orm migration to accept a path starting with src/ in the import statement when including other entities?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered this problem for 2 days. I've been scratching my head why typeorm cli does not respect the 'baseUrl' setting in my tsconfig.json. I think i found the solution. So if you look at another script in the package.json:

```
"test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand"
```

there is this module called [tsconfig-paths/register](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths). I searched about it, and bingo! It does help with resolving import path while respecting 'baseUrl' in tsconfig.json. So i modified my typeorm script in package.json like this:

```
"typeorm": "node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

And then it works like a charm. Thanks.